# is.element on column of lists in data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame with a column that contains some elements that are lists.  I would like to find out which rows of the data frame contain a keyword in that column.

The data frame, df, looks a bit like this

```
idstr                tag
1                 wl
2           other.to
3         other.from
4 c("wl","other.to")
5                 wl
6           other.wl
7 c("ll","other.to")
```

The goal is to assign all of the rows with 'wl' in their tag to a new data frame.  In this example, I would want a new data frame that looks like:

```
idstr  tag
1      wl
4      c("wl","other.to")
5      wl
```

I tried something like this

> df_wl <- df[which(is.element('wl',df$tag)),]

but this only returns the first element of the data frame (whether or not it contains 'wl').  I think the trouble lies in iterating through the rows and implementing the "is.element" function.  Here are two implementations of the function and it's results:

```
is.element('wl',df$tag[[4]]) >  TRUE
is.element('wl',df$tag[4]) >  FALSE
```

How do you suggest I iterate through the dataframe to assign df_wl with it's proper values?

PS:  Here's the dput:

```
structure(list(idstr = 1:7, tag = structure(c(6L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 1L), .Label =     c("c(\"ll\",\"other.to\")", "c(\"wl\",\"other.to\")", "other.wl", "other.from", "other.to", "wl"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("idstr", "tag"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What about `df[sapply(df$tag, function(x) any(x == "wl")),]`

Comment: Have you tried using `grep`?

Comment: thanks Richard.  It worked with this small example, but when I applied it on my main dataset, it returned a data frame with 'NA' values for every element.  I think the 'any(x == "wl")' worked because the new data frame seems like the right size, so now it might be an issue with returning the data

Comment: Yeah, my idea of your data was not correct.  I've edited my answer based on your `dput`

Comment: In your example dataframe, `tag` is a factor, not a list. In particular, `c('wl','other.to')` is just a literal string label, not representing a vector of strings. Text processing (e.g. `grep`) can work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your `dput` data. this may work.  The regular expression `(^wl$)|(\"wl\")` matches `wl` from beginning to end, or any occurrence of `"wl"` (wrapped in double quotes)

```
df[grepl("(^wl$)|(\"wl\")", df$tag),]
#   idstr                tag
# 1     1                 wl
# 4     4 c("wl","other.to")
# 5     5                 wl
```

Comment: Why not `df[grepl("^wl$|'wl'", df$tag),]`? The first part of the regular expression is `wl` by itself, the second looks for `wl` in single quotes.

Comment: SO CLOSE!  I guess I didn't provide all of the edge cases with that dput.  Some of the lists could not contain wl like 'c("ll","other.from").  Here's another dput:  structure(list(idstr = 1:7, tag = structure(c(6L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 
6L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("c(\"ll\",\"other.to\")", "c(\"wl\",\"other.to\")", 
"ll", "other.from", "other.to", "wl"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("idstr", 
"tag"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: @BrianDiggs - I was actually about to post that exact regex

Comment: You seemed to be iterating to that result, which is why I didn't want to put up a competing answer.

Comment: @zebrainatree You should add that example to your question; comments can disappear and aren't supposed to be for anything permanent.

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping me format this question better.  I updated the example data frame and dput to better account for edge cases.  The most recent response only returns responses with just "wl", i need it to include lists that contain "wl" while excluding elements like "other.wl"

Comment: BOOM!  Thank You so much, @RichardScriven!  Brian and tcash, thank you for your contributions as well, I appreciate it